# How to check if the "Transform" array has duplicates?

Tags: c++, arrays, transformation, unreal-engine4

I have an array of type transform, and I want to find all the existing rows in this array in a local variable of type type transform and check if there are any duplicates in the array and remove that duplicated row or randomize it in the range specified.
To make it more clear I will add the code which will show exactly what I want to achieve.

I have a class we call it **MyActor**

**MyActor.h**

```
void RandomLocation(TArray<FTransform> &Arr, FTransform &Row);
```

**MyActor.cpp**

```
void AMyActor::RandomLocation(TArray<FTransform> &Arr, FTransform &Row)
{
    Row = Arr[FMath::RandRange(0, Available.Num() - 1)];
}

int Main()
{
    FTransform RowLocal {}; //to represent all the available rows in the array
    TArray<FTransform> ArrLocal {}; //List of transforms, lets take range[0 to 99]
    TArray<FTransform> TempArrLocal {}; // used to find the list of arrays and return its INDEX

    RandomLocation(ArrLocal, RowLocal); // Takes two parameters and randomized the range by -1

    if (TempArrLocal.Find(RowLocal) == -1)
    {
        //Log: Unable to find duplicate in the array
    }
    else
    {
        //Log: Successfully found the duplicate in the array
        //Repeating re-randomizing the range of the array by calling RandomLocation();
        RandomLocation(ArrLocal, RowLocal);
    }
}
```

Running this Logic gives me the error:

> Severity Error Code C2678          binary ‘==’: no operator found which
> takes a left-hand operand of type ‘const FTransform’ (or there is no
> acceptable Conversion

**Temporary Solution, I am not satisfied with this.**

```
if (ArrLocal.ContainsByPredicate([RowLocal](const FTransform Transform)
    {
        return Transform.GetLocation() == RowLocal.GetLocation()
            && Transform.GetRotation() == RowLocal.GetRotation()
            && Transform.GetScale3D() == RowLocal.GetScale3D();
    }))
    {
                    //Log: Successfully found the duplicate in the array
            //Repeating re-randomizing the range of the array by calling RandomLocation();
            RandomLocation(ArrLocal, RowLocal);
    }
    else
    { //Log: Unable to find duplicate in the array }
```

Comment: `int Main()` -- This is not real C++ code.  Please post a [mcve].  *Running this Logic gives me the error:* -- You are not running the program - the program is being compiled.  Which line of code is giving this error?

Comment: int Main can be any function you will implement the logic, the main thing is the random location function and then rechecking the values in the if statement.

Comment: `(TempArrLocal.Find(RowLocal) == -1)`  this line of code is giving the error

Comment: `FTransform RowLocal {}; FTransform RowLocal2 {}; if ( RowLocal == RowLocal2) {}` -- Does that compile?  Does it give the same error?  If so, then the reason is that the compiler has no idea how to compare `FTransform` objects, which obviously the `Find` function is also attempting to do.

Comment: Do you want a solution that uses Find()?, FTransform does not have == operator but you can use Equals function with a loop.

Comment: yes `if ( RowLocal == RowLocal2)` compiles because it is not comparison by Array, and returning a single index, but I want to check each index of all rows in the array

Comment: @unlut yes, but doing this in blueprint the find function works perfectly...  I even tried the blueprint library which it used, but in c++ it gives the same error even the bp math library

Comment: @unlut @PaulMcKenzie Edited the question and added a `Temporary Solution` at the end of the code, but I am not satisfied with this.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to work and copy the FTransforms? Why dont you just use indices into the FTransforms of ArrLocal?

Comment: @Nadir yes, I will spawn an object at the random location in the level which can be done only by using recording the locations range in FVector and processing them by FTransform.location   i will not be changing the rotation and scale , I am getting the locations from the vectors as `worldTransform`

Comment: Is this you asking same question in unreal engine forums? https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/binary-no-operator-found-ftransform-ftransform/628457/51. I think answer here is pretty clear, operator == is not defined for FTransform so you can not use Find method. You should ask details about why operator== is not available in unreal engine forums.

Comment: @Nadir this ArrLocal will store these locations in the array of range between 0 to the range of recorded locations array, I can store them in the datatable of a struct which has a variable of trype `FVector` , lets call that variable Location

Comment: @JasmineKakarva you can still do the filtering using indices, once you have found a FTransform that fits the constraints, you simply retrieve it with ArrLocal[myIndex]

Comment: @JasmineKakarva -- The error boils down to a C++ issue -- it has nothing to do with unreal engine.  When C++ uses `==` it requires that `operator ==` be defined for the types being used.  If it isn't defined, then it is what it is.  You have to write (overload) `operator ==` for that type.  If the code you wrote is what needs to be done, then so be it.  If there is a faster way to compare items using your criteria, then use that.  Bottom line is that out-of-the-box `==` will not work unless you tell C++ how to compare.

Comment: @unlut its already 4th day I am waiting on UE Forum for an working solution , I am in this trouble from 4 days and I ask this question on many forums , I really need a solution for this, my study is stopped at this point if I will not solve this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you mean something like extending the engine code or adding something in `myUtils` ?

Comment: @Nadir write an answer if you know it will work , let me try your solution

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have an idea to add that overload since `if statement` is using a bool to comparing `true/false`, how to add one additional operator overload like `static bool IsEqual_Transform(const FTransform& A, const FTransform& B);`

Comment: this is what the engine is missing I think